# Uploading Files Using ASP.NET Web Forms, Generic Handler and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am following this article http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f2a2f1ee-e18a-416b-893e-883c800f83f4.aspx

I am unable to get it to work.  I use chrome to look at the javascript when it's running and it saying
var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);  is undefined.  When I look in the html portion, this is what it generated

```
 <input type="file" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FileUpload1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1" />
```

I am using jquery 1.9 and asp.net webform. Any advice?

The goal is to only upload certain file extension and display back to user if upload was successful or invalid file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1")
```

With an `id` selector there is really no reason to treat it like a list of jQuery elements.

Also, you can disable this feature that garbles up ids in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard in jquery to find any elements that end with "FileUpload1", essentially ignoring all the extra content ASP.NET generates with the following:

```
$("[id$=FileUpload1]")
```

That should work for you.